# Java listIterator - swap 2 values

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, insertion-sort

I have an ordered ArrayList of strings: I wrote this static method to keep it sorted, i use it every time an element is is added to the ArrayList.

Using listIterator, I start from the last value of ArrayList N:
if N-1 comes after N I invert the two values. Then I go to cell n-1, and repeat the same procedure, until i reach the end of ArrayList.

In this code I am unable to invert **current** with **prev**: what am I doing wrong?

```
public static void sort(ArrayList arr, String s){

    if(arr.size()>1){

        ListIterator<String> iterator = arr.listIterator(arr.size());
    
        while(iterator.hasPrevious()){
            String current = iterator.previous();
            String prev = iterator.previous();    
            if(compare(current,prev) < 0){
                
                iterator.set(current);
                iterator.next();
                iterator.set(prev);
                iterator.previous();

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: `I wrote this static method to keep it sorted,` It's often better to encapsulate behavior.  A `Tree` is a collection that keeps its elements sorted.

Comment: You are right, in this case i wrote this as an exercise.
Could you tell me why i can't invert current with temp?
Many thanks.

Comment: One problem I have is you never actually explain what you are doing.  Your routine is called "sort" but it can't sort a list with only one loop.  Then you never do anything at all with the string parameter `s`.  The code is obviously incomplete, and so is the question.  Please either fix it up so that both are clear, or start over with a new question.

Comment: In this case only one loop is sufficient, as the array is kept sorted (n0 < n1 < ... < an).
Every time I make an insertion, I put the element to add at the bottom of the array, using the add () method of ArrayList, in position N. Later I call the sort function; since I use the insertionSort, I only need the inner loop, as I am going to invert the element N-1 with N if N-1 > N (obviously with the strings I do the lexicographic comparison). I stop when this condition is no longer true or i reach the end of the array.
As for the s parameter, you are right, it is not needed nor used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation of [`ListIterator#set(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)) we can read

> Replaces the last element returned by `next()` or `previous()` with the specified element

So lets see what happens in your swapping code for data like `arr=["b", "c", "a"]`.

I will mark *position* of iterator with `<` or `>` to point out ***direction of potential `set` method***.

So it will be

- `[elementE] <  elementF` if it was called after `next()` which returned `elementE`
- `elementD  > [elementE]` if it was called after `previous()` which returned `elementE`

##### Lets take a look at code you are using to swap elements.

```
iterator.set(current); //1
iterator.next();       //2
iterator.set(prev);    //3
iterator.previous();   //4
```

Before its execution, state of your application (iterator and variables) is

```
//current = "a"; prev="c", arr=["b", "c", "a"]
"b" > "c" "a"  
     |
   position of iterator
```

So since iterator ***points to*** element `"c"` it would be replaced if we call `set` now.

After calling `iterator.set(current);` where `current="a"` state of application will change to

```
//current = "a"; prev="c", arr=["b", "a", "a"]
"b" > "a" "a"  //`iterator.set` doesn't affect "position" of iterator
```

Now after `iterator.next();` it will become

```
//current = "a"; prev="c", arr=["b", "a", "a"]
"b" "a" < "a"  //notce iterator was moved between "a" and "a" 
               //but points at *left* "a"
```

#### And here is your problem.

**Take a look at direction of iterator** (which is `<`) and again read documentation quoted at start of this answer. Currently `iterator.set(prev);` will replace `"a"` in the *middle*, not at the *end* because it was middle element which was returned by either `next()` or `previous()` as last element.

If you want to replace last `"a"` you need iterator to "*point at*" that element. So you want to create situation like

1. `"b" "a" > "a"`   - points from left
2. or `"b" "a" "a" <` - points from right

(also remember to set iterator after swapping in position like `"b" "a" < "a"` or `"b" "a" > "a"` so it would be "before" two next elements which we want to compare).

In case 1 your swapping code can look like

```
//"b" > "c" "a"
iterator.set(current); //"b" > current "a"
iterator.next();       //"b" current < "a"
iterator.next();       //"b" current "a" <
iterator.previous();   //"b" current > "a" 
iterator.set(prev);    //"b" current > prev
```

(I will leave code for case 2 as your homework)

---

BTW you need to handle case where new element is smallest in entire list (like in scenario in current answer with `["b", "c", "a"]` (you will need nested `iterator.hasPrevious()`)

Comment: I'm going to point out that when you have a problem like this, some small and reasonably self contained method that is not working as expected, what the Peshmo did here is to design a small test case that allows the bug to be discovered.  These sorts of small tests are often called "unit tests" and are fundamental to writing code that works.  Please please please look up unit testing, use those tests all the time, and also get Martin Fowler's *Refactoring* and read the introduction where he talks about how and why to use unit tests.